# Debug exception binding to List item when is empty

Tags: wpf, list, xaml, exception, binding

Having this piece of code:

```
<ContentControl
    Content="{Binding SelectedDispositivos[0]}" 
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DispositivoInfoViewTemplate}">
</ContentControl>
```

SelectedDispositivos is a List of items bounded to DataGrid SelectedItems property. That list can be empty, so it throws an exception like this:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'DispositivoViewModel')
from 'SelectedDispositivos' (type 'ObservableCollection`1'). 
BindingExpression:Path=SelectedDispositivos[0]; DataItem='DispositivosViewModel'  
(HashCode=45398538); target element is 'ContentControl' (Name=''); target property is  
'Content' (type 'Object') 
ArgumentOutOfRangeException:'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: El argumento 
especificado está fuera del intervalo de valores válidos.
Nombre del parámetro: index'
```

It only happens in Results window on debug mode, and the application continue running without problems. Anyway, an exception is an exception, so i want to know if there is an easy way to fix it, without having another variable in ViewModel to expose FirstSelectedItem or something like that.

**Edit:**

Even doint it with DataTriggers, its throwing the same binding error. I removed the DataTrigger Content setter and the problem was gone, to ensure the problem is there:

```
<ContentControl
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DispositivoInfoViewTemplate}">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedDispositivos.Count}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding SelectedDispositivos[0]}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Those are usually referred to as binding errors...

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` on `SelectedDispositivos.Count = 0` which sets the `Content` to **null** or something else. The default binding needs to be moved to a `Setter` so it won't [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) the `DataTrigger`.

Comment: Oh my.. im using DataTriggers on the whole app, even at that ContentControl to make it visible when Count = 1. Dunno why i didnt thought about that solution.

Thanks for guiding me on the correct path ;)

Comment: Hmm, wait, even with that is throwing the same binding error when i select the item at the DataGrid O_o. I Update the first post. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the content binding updates before the DataTrigger, in that case this won't do. (Also i don't think that an additional VM property would be much of an issue.) You could use a conveter that returns the first item or null, but before doing that i'd take the logic to the VM...

Comment: As you seem to work with collections i'd look into [`CollectionViews`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx), then you can bind to the `CurrentItem` via `Dispositivos/` and don't need to mess with a separate collection.

Comment: Finally i used a VM property, seems the easiest solution. Anyway, i still need a separate collection because i can select multiple items at a time to remove and other commands. Thanks for your help!